# How to add together two of the lowest value numbers here?

Tags: javascript

How do I have to edit the "answer" here to get it to add together two of the lowest numbers?

```
var luku1, luku2, luku3, luku4, answer; 


luku1 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 1"));   

luku2 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 2"));

luku3 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 3"));

luku4 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 4"));


answer = luku1 + luku2;

document.write (answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort variables and add first 2 values.

```js
var luku1, luku2, luku3, luku4, answer; 

luku1 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 1"));   
luku2 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 2"));
luku3 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 3"));
luku4 = parseInt(prompt("Give number 4"));

var arr = [luku1, luku2, luku3, luku4].sort(function(a,b){
  return a>b?1:a<b?-1:0;
}) 
answer = arr[0] + arr[1];

document.write (answer);
```

You can also try something like this as well:

```js
var inputs = [], answer, n = 4;
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  inputs.push(parseInt(prompt("Give number 1")));
}

var arr = inputs.sort(function(a,b){
  return a>b?1:a<b?-1:0;
}) 
answer = arr[0] + arr[1];

document.write (answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the numbers in an array, after you have all of the input, sort the array, and sum the elements at index 0 and 1.

```
var luku = [];
var answer; 

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
  luku.push(parseInt(prompt("Give number " + i)));

luku.sort();

answer = luku[0] + luku[1];

document.write(answer);
```